# Web Client with multi-panels implementation and management

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-ui

I was looking for a good solution to my need of implementing a web client application (HTML + JavaScript + AngularJS) and found something that very well satisfies my need in [here](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/demos/complex.html#).

In fact, I clicked on the link reading **Click here to CREATE the Inner Layout** and (using Chrome's debugger) copied the whole page as-is (except for replacing `body` and `\body` to `div`s).

Also, added to the index page all the required links.

When accessing the specific page, I get errors and obviously a not working result as shown in the image.

It complains about not being able to read a `split` property.

Here is the section where all the references are mentioned within the index page header:

```
    <script src="Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery.layout-latest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
```

and the screenshot:
[image: Erros]

Can anyone suggest where the problem is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's jquery file proble in that example he used **jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.0** version but you have used latest **jquery 3.1.1**

Comment: OK @bipinpatel, I'll try replacing the jQuery version and post here the result (will take few days though). Thanks for the prompt response.